# Why doesn't $class->SUPER::new call the constructors of all parent classes when using multiple inheritance?

Tags: perl, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to use multiple inheritance in Perl, but I can't figure out how to call multiple parent constructors from the child constructor.

A.pm:

```
package A;
use Carp qw (croak);
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    print "This is A new\n";
    my $self->{DEV_TYPE} = shift || "A";
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

sub a_func{
    print "This is A func\n";
}

1;
```

B.pm:

```
package B;
use Carp qw (croak);
use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    print "This is B new\n";
    my $self->{DEV_TYPE} = shift || "B";
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

sub b_func{
    print "This is B func\n";
}

1;
```

C.pm:

```
package C;
use Carp qw (croak);
use strict;
use warnings;
eval "use A";
die $@ if $@;
eval "use B";
die $@ if $@;
our @ISA = ("A","B");

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);
    print "This is C new\n";
    $self->{DEV_TYPE} = shift || "C";
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

sub c_func{
    print "This is C func\n";
}

1;
```

In `C::new`, `$class->SUPER::new` doesn't call the constructor for B. If I call it explicitly with `$class->B::new(@_);`, I get the error

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "B" at C.pm

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$class->SUPER::new(@_)` will only pick one of the items in`@ISA`, since else it would need to return an array of object references( one reference for `A->new()` and one reference for `B->new()`)

Comment: See also *"Method Resolution Order"* in [`perlobj`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) and [`mro`](https://metacpan.org/pod/mro)

Comment: You could force it to call the `B` class constructor with  `my $selfB = do {        local @ISA = ("B");  $class->SUPER::new(@_)   };` but I don't know if that is a good idea

Answer (score 8):

`$class->SUPER::new` always calls `A::new` because A comes before B in `@ISA`. See [method resolution order](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Resolution-Order) in perlobj:

> When a class has multiple parents, the method lookup order becomes more complicated.
>
> By default, Perl does a depth-first left-to-right search for a method. That means it starts with the first parent in the `@ISA` array, and then searches all of its parents, grandparents, etc. If it fails to find the method, it then goes to the next parent in the original class's `@ISA` array and searches from there.

This means that `$class->SUPER::new` will only call one of the parent constructors. If you have initialization logic in both parent classes that needs to be run from the child, move it into separate methods as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5251334).

---

When you explicitly call `B::new` with `$class->B::new`, you get

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "B" at C.pm

because `use B` is loading the [core module B](http://perldoc.perl.org/B.html) instead of your module. You should rename your module.

---

Note that it's better to use the [`parent`](http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html) pragma instead of setting `@ISA` manually, e.g

```
use parent qw(Parent1 Parent2);
```

`parent` takes care of loading the parent modules, so you can drop the associated `use` statements (which you shouldn't be `eval`ing, by the way).

Comment: Thanks, the B issue is solved - now it is D.
However, even though i changed it to use parent, it still doesn't make D contractor when i run `my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@_);`

Comment: @OmerLevy See my edit. Only one `new` method will be called. If you want to call both, you should move the initialization into separate subs as described [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=188985).